# How to restart/kill all cloud run instances

Tags: google-cloud-run

Lets say I implement some caching on cloud run start, like google suggests in its own documentation: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips/general#using_global_variables

But my data sometimes change and I would like to update the cache. Since cloud run cannot do async task in the background, my only option is to tell cloud run to kill all the instances and create new ones.

How to do that without deploying a new revision?

Or can I deploy new revision without building a new container?

Thank you

Comment: 1) Do not depend on behavior such as global variables. 2) You cannot kill Cloud run containers except by forcing a software exception which will then cold start that container, but there is no interface to all containers. 3) Cloud Run supports always on CPUs, you can run tasks asynchronously at an increased cost. 4) Maybe you can use an age value and update/invalidate the cache if older than X seconds/minutes/hours.

Comment: Thank you @JohnHanley. I was thinking about your proposed solution number 4, but the question is when to execute the code? I would have to execute the cache rebuild while executing the request, therefore that single request would have a high latency. Or can I create a request from cloud run to the same instance of cloud run (so do a request on localhost for example) ?Thank you

Comment: A strange workaround could be to deploy 2 Cloud Run revisions with the same container version. When you want to reload cache, you can switch traffic from 1 revision to the other one.  Never tested, but it should work.

Comment: Thank you @guillaumeblaquiere. Thats really interesting and could work, since the unused will scale to zero. Do you know how to deploy the same container twice? Thank you

Comment: Perform 2 deployments!! That's all! Each deployment will create a new revision.

Comment: Is it a shared cache? If so, define a Cloud Run Job to reset the cache.

Comment: you can also add a label. that will create a copy of the current one :)

Answer (score 1):

For time-based refresh, you can mark instance start time in some global state inside your container. Then you can configure [healthchecks](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/healthchecks) for your CloudRun instance to check current vs start time and report as unhealthy if it's time to be replaced.