# abort Cloud Run request that is already running

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

note: I see there is a question that has a similar title [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71728497/how-to-restart-kill-all-cloud-run-instances) but my situation is different from this OP

I have a Cloud Run that executes a process for 20+ minutes. Sometimes I need to abort this request in the middle because I find something I need to fix in my Cloud Run code.
The problem is that some misconfigurations can only be found after a certain amount of time has passed, so testing the Cloud Run process in small chunks is not an option.

Is there a way to kill a running Cloud Run process that is executed via an HTTP request?

Comment: if the service interact with others Google Cloud services, is to delete the Cloud Run runtime service account, or to remove all the role on it. You will stop the process because of permission error. Else, if it's a standalone processing, I think that disabling the billing is the fastest way to stop any process...You can also delete the service, but it should take longer that the billing option. In any case, there is no kill switch.